# Dagger 2 - Not generating xxxModule_xxxFactory classes

Tags: android, kotlin, dagger-2, dagger

I'm working with Dagger2 in a multi-module project and Im having an issue with one module in particular.

I have a Room database that I'm injecting into Repository classes. The module for that looks something like this:

```
@Module
class RoomModule(app: Application) {
   private val database = AppDatabase.getInstance(app)

   @Provides
   @Singleton
   fun provideModelDao() = database.getModelDao()

   @Provides
   @Singleton
   fun provideAnotherModelDao() = database.getAnotherModelDao()
}
```

And my repository classes look like this:

```
class ModelRepository @Inject constructor(private val modelDao: ModelDao) {
    fun doFooWithModel() {
       // Do foo
    }
}
```

My repository classes are used by UseCase classes, that look something like this:

```
class DoFooUseCase @Inject constructor(private val repository: ModelRepository) {
    fun doFoo() {
        repository.doFooWithModel()
    }
}
```

And finally, Im using this UseCase class in a `WebClient` implementation class.

```
class MyWebClient @Inject constructor(private val fooUseCase: DoFooUseCase): WebClient() {
    // Web client stuff
}
```

Here, no problem.

The problem comes when I inject the WebClient into an activity.

```
class WebActivity : AppCompatActivity() {

   @Inject
   lateinit var webClient: MyWebClient    

    override fun onCreate(savedStateInstance: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedStateInstance)
        AndroidInjection.inject(this)
        webView.webViewClient = webClient
    }
}
```

Now, after building the project, I get this error:

```
MyApplicationComponent.java:24: error: cannot find symbol:
RoomModule_ProvideModelDAOFactory;
```

But, oddly enough, when I remove the `@Inject` annotation from the activity, the Dagger component builds correctly. But obviously, the app doesn't work because the `lateinit var` are not being injected.

What are those `xxFactory` classes and how can I make dagger generate them? What am I missing here? I had used dagger like this in other projects and I haven't had this issue before.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

EDIT.

To someone else having this issue.

I was missing the `Dagger Compiler` dependency in the module containing the Room classes.

the dependency is:

`kapt com.google.dagger:dagger-compiler:$dagger_version`

or `annotationProcessor` if you are using JAVA instead of Kotlin.